# Why is does refreshApex need to return the method?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, wire, refreshapex

Given the below LWC JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.getRecords';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement {

    wiredResult;

    @wire(getRecords) wiredRecords(result) {

        this.wiredResult = result; 

        if (result.data) { ... }
        else if (result.error) { ... }
    }

    refresh() {
        return refreshApex(this.wiredResult); 
    }
}
```

Why does `refreshApex` need to `return` the method?

Reference: [Salesforce Developer Guide: Call Apex Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. We use refreshApex without such a requirement. That same documentation specifies the signature for refreshApex as:

> refreshApex(*valueProvisionedByWireService*)

I.e. there is no return value, so doing `return refreshApex(value)` simply returns undefined, which is equivalent to not using a return statement at all.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Interesting, so the examples in the documentation are at best misleading, or just wrong?.... would be nice to get an official answer from someone in the Lightning team (no offence) :-)

Comment: No offence taken - the code samples simply have cruft in them, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the returned value, but refreshApex does return a promise which is often times useful. If you want logic to fire after the completion of the refresh (usually meaning using the latest version of the data), then you need to interact with the promise since it happens asynchronously. The returned promise can be chained so in your example there could be a method that is written

```
handleNextClick = () => {
    // Do some save logic here

    // Then call refresh() which returns refreshApex()
    refresh().then(() => {
        // Do some logic now that you have the most up to date data.
    });
}
```

Without returning the promise that refreshApex() provides you, you couldn't run code that only ran after it completed.
They also give some other examples in the documentation you reference above.

```
handleClick(e) {
    updateOpptyStage({
        amount: this.amount,
        stage: 'Closed Won'
    })
    .then(() => {
        return refreshApex(this.opptiesOverAmount);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.message = 'Error received: code' + error.errorCode + ', ' +
            'message ' + error.body.message;
    });
}
```

You can also use async/await to wait on the refreshApex to finish, but I think that's out of the scope of your question.